# Existence of Bases implies Axiom of multiple choice. How to 'choose' $b \in B_i$.

Tags: set-theory

Im currently reading the Proof of Andreas Blass, that the existence of a Basis for any vector space implies the axiom of (multiple) choice but i am stuck with 2 things:
[Proof](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Eablass/bases-AC.pdf) (Theorem 2)

1. It is said that the rational functions that are i-homogenous for all $ i \in I $ give a subfield. Is zero missing here or am i missing something in the definition of homogenous?
2. $F_i$ is defined as the Set of those members of $X_i$ which occur in the denominator of the unique representative in reduced form of the value $\beta_{bi}$ 'for some $b$ in $B_i$' ($B_i$ is finite and non-empty). The issue i have is that i don't see how i am allowed to choose a member $b$ of $B_i$ when trying to define a function $i \mapsto F_i$.

Comment: The zero is homogeneous of every degree.

Comment: ok If we put deg(zero_polynomial) = 0 i see that zero is homogenous of every non-negative degree. Is that somewhat typical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this version of the proof it became clear to me what is done:
[Link](https://caicedoteaching.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/502-equivalents-of-the-axiom-of-choice/) (7 $\rightarrow$ 1)

If we denote $A(b,i)$ to be the Set of those members of $X_i$ which occur in the denominator of the unique representative in reduced form of the value $\beta_{bi}$ then $$F_i:=\bigcup_{b \in B_i}A(b,i).$$
which is of course *not* dependant on a $b \in B_i$.

I originally didn't see that a union of these $A(b,i)$'s was meant and wondered how we are allowed to choose a $b \in B_i$ (we are not).